# Some questions about emacs mode

Tags: emacs

As we know, mode is very important in emacs. But I feel I am not very clear about how to set it. For example, I often see something like (***-mode 1) or (***-mode) in .emacs file. And some tutorials also say that a mode can be set by M-x ***-mode. Could you tell me what's the differences between them and how to use them? Thanks!

Comment: `(***-mode 1)` or `(***-mode)` generally do the same thing -- i.e., turn it **on** programmatically.  When the number is negative or 0, the mode turns **off** programmatically.  `M-x` is for a situation when the user turns it on/off by hand.

Comment: You should probably read the Emacs tutorial. Try pressing `Ctrl`+`H`, then `T` (or as the Emacs docs would say, `C-h t`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lisp [function](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Functions.html) is a piece of code which declares a name for another piece of code to be executed later.

```
(defun hello ()
   (message "Hiya!"))
```

Now, you can invoke the named code from anywhere else in Lisp.

```
(hello)
```

Only at this point does the `message` form get executed.

Many Lisp functions contain an [`interactive`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Call.html#Interactive-Call) form which specifies how they should behave when called interactively (for example, should it prompt for an argument, or use the cursor or mouse position as the argument, etc). Those which do can be invoked with `M-x` and the function name.

A [major mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Modes.html#Modes) specifies a function which sets up some variables to exclusively control the behavior of Emacs. For example, [`M-x text-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Mode.html) sets a (very basic) regime for word wrapping and cursor movement which is suitable for text files. When you are in text mode, you cannot be in C++ mode, or Lisp mode, or fundamental mode. These are other major modes which define different or additional functionality suitable for editing other types of text.

Because a major mode is exclusive, it is usually a function which doesn't take any arguments. So to put the current buffer in text mode, the Lisp code is simply

```
(text-mode)
```

[Minor modes,](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minor-Modes.html) by contrast, specify additional behavior which is independent from the major mode. For example, Overwrite mode specifies a different behavior when inserting text before some other text -- normally, Emacs pushes any existing text ahead, but when overwrite mode is active, existing text in front of the cursor will be replaced as you type.

You can have multiple minor modes active at any time -- you could have flyspell (spell checking as you type), tool bar mode, menu bar mode, and line number mode active at the same time as you are in text mode and overwrite mode.

Because of this, a common (though not universal) convention for minor modes is to perform a toggle. When you are already in toolbar mode, `M-x toolbar-mode` will disable this minor mode. To unambiguously disable the mode, pass it a negative numeric argument;

```
(toolbar-mode -1)
```

Without the argument, the code will toggle -- the result will depend on whether the mode was already active, or not.

(As noted in a comment, this changed in Emacs 24; I'm describing the historical behavior.)

Comment: That's a nice detailed answer. Just note that, starting with Emacs 24, calling a minor mode *in code* with no arguments always enables the mode. If the mode it was already enabled, it remains enabled.